# Specflow - Can you gather all integration test steps to be run as system test against a real server?

Tags: specflow

I have a number of sub-projects in my solution, each with their own Specflow integration tests. These are all run against a local web server instance (Kestrel). What I'd like to do is create a new project which pulls together all the existing tests in the solution and runs them against a live server. This will obviously only be run occasionally.

Is this possible without redefining the steps?

Comment: Without seeing some of the step definitions we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Do you really need to create a new project for this? With a command line call of `dotnet test` or `vstest.console.exe` you can execute the tests in multiple assemblies. If you put the configuration in an external file or an environment variable, you can so specify your server.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible if you can make the root URL that Selenium or your web service calls use configurable. Depending on whether you use .NET Core (appsettings.json) or Framework (App.config) add some settings in those configuration files to define the root URL. Simply change that root URL in the config file and run the tests.

An alternative would be to define an environment variable that holds this root URL, but a config setting would be ideal. The trick is to use this config setting in each place you access URLs to your application or web services. It probably would not be difficult to create a class specifically for this purpose:

```cs
internal class TestUrls
{
    private readonly string rootUrl;

    internal string HomePage => rootUrl;

    internal TestUrls(string rootUrl)
    {
        this.rootUrl = rootUrl;
    }

    internal string UserProfilePage(string username)
    {
        return $"{rootUrl}/profiles/{username}";
    }

    internal string UpdateUserWebService(string username)
    {
        return $"{rootUrl}/users/{username}";
    }
}
```

Then in a `[BeforeScenario]` hook initialize and register this with the SpecFlow dependency injection framework:

```cs
[Binding]
public class SpecFlowHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;

    public SpecFlowHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        var rootUrl = // read from config file
        var urls = new TestUrls(rootUrl);

        container.RegisterInstanceAs(urls);
    }
}
```

Use the TestUrls object by defining it as a constructor parameter in your step definition classes:

```cs
[Binding]
public class UserSteps
{
    private readonly TestUrls urls;

    public UserSteps(TestUrls urls)
    {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    [When(@"the ""(.*)"" user views their profile")]
    public void WhenTheUserViewsTheirProfile(string username)
    {
        // Generate dynamic URL to user profile page based on argument in step
        var userProfilePageUrl = urls.UserProfilePage(username);

        // navigate to use profile page
    }
}
```